# Do substances dissolved in a solvent oxidise?

Tags: solvents

If a substance is dissolved in a solvent does it still oxidise? Does it depend on weather the solvent can dissolve oxygen?

Comment: There are very many reagents that will oxidise substances in solution

Comment: The rate would be slower if oxygen does not dissolve in the solvent, but at the interface the solute would still be in contact with the atmosphere (assuming that's the source of the oxygen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only can things be oxidized in solution, but in some cases (such as ferrous chloride) exposure to air can contaminate your solution with oxidation products.  Such solutions should be stored in a way that prevents or at least retards air from getting in (e.g., taping around the lid).